# Attempting to access data from JavaScript .json object with {object}.#text location

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I'm attempting to access the text value of a JavaScript .json object with under the location of loggie.stats.Wins. Under the Wins column there are 3 subcategories listed: @category, @abbreviation, and #text. I'm particularly interested in the value of #text, but when I attempt:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(loggie.stats.Wins.#text))
```

I receive the error SyntaxError: {app location}\src\App.js: Unknown PrivateName "#text"

I'm assuming there is something about the @ and # tags in a json object I do not understand, but I don't know where to look. I can stringify the whole .Wins object and pull it from there I suppose but I'm guessing there is a less convoluted way to go about it.

EDIT: MisterJojo gave me the solution, I needed to access it as loggie.stats.Wins['#text']. I'm hoping he can point me towards a reading source so I can explain in greater detail how the answer works here.

Comment: Can you paste a sample JSON being received?

Comment: rookie question from rookie programmer, what's the easiest way to copy/paste it? I'm getting it from a fetch request, when I console.log it it'll show me the JS object but I can't copy/paste that. I can stringify the response, is that sufficient?

Comment: `I can't copy paste that` - Just a part of it, with dummy values, but the keys as it is would suffice

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(loggie.stats.Wins['#text'] ))` should be the solution

Comment: @MisterJojo that did it! I feel like that's something I've seen before, but I can't recall what it is. Is the ['#text'] a property of Wins? I thought it might be something like that since Wins was capitalized, but I couldn't find anything easily on Google.

Comment: no, that's just how js works, or we get to the elements with the point as a separator, or with their bracketed wording. it's part of the Javascript B.A.BA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the dot notation to access JSON fields with names like that.

In your example you probably should do `loggie.stats.Wins["#text"]` instead.

You can only use the dot notation when your field contains alphanumeric letters only (without space, or special characters with the exception of underscore `_`), and it must start with an alphabetic character or underscore

e.g.: valid ones:

```
object.fIelD1234

object.field_name

object._abc
```

invalid:

```
object.123abc

object.ab-cd
```

with special characters you will have to access that field with `[]`

e.g.

```
object['123abc']

object['ab cd']

object['#123a']
```

Comment: Credit also to @MisterJojo who answered the question in the comments while you were typing up this detailed answer. Thanks for your help gentlemen, probably an easy question but I'm still learning!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use .#text it is an invalid syntax.

If the Json key is #text, you can access this property like this `Wins['#text']`

Comment: Thanks for the response! I figured there was something like this going on but I couldn't figure out the syntax. I tried back ticks and inserting it into a string literal but had no luck with either of those.